# Serving SvelteKit app through VSCode Webview API

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, svelte, vscode-extensions, sveltekit

This question is being asked after spending weeks and giving up multiple times on trying to solve this.

I'm developing a VSCode extension that needs to make use of the [Webview API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview). For a while, this could be using Svelte, but now with SvelteKit released as stable and being treated as default when you do `npm create svelte`, I targetted to use that. After configuring the app to be static SPA with SSR turned off and using the `@sveltejs/adapter-static`, it seems that serving it is not the same as it was with vanilla Svelte.

This is the `svelte.config.js`:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/**
 * Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
 * for more information about preprocessors
 *
 * @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
export default {
  preprocess: preprocess(),
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({ fallback: 'index.html' }),
    // ssr: false, // deprecated
    csp: {
      directives: {
        'default-src': ['none'],
        'img-src': ['{{cspSource}} https:'],
        'script-src': ['{{cspSource}}'],
        'style-src': ['{{cspSource}}'],
      },
    },
    // paths: {
    //   base: '{{baseURL}}', // not accepted
    // },
  },
};
```

This is the built HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="default-src 'none'; img-src {{cspSource}} https:; script-src {{cspSource}} 'sha256-N2DRY+AREasGSTE5X4BdHoEYZsaGOpTvUwTBIHmryVA='; style-src {{cspSource}}">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/start-e16b6a0f.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/index-0576dc7c.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/singletons-51070258.js">
  </head>
  <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
    <div style="display: contents">
        <script type="module" data-sveltekit-hydrate="45h">
            import { start } from "/_app/immutable/start-e16b6a0f.js";

            start({
                env: {},
                paths: {"base":"","assets":""},
                target: document.querySelector('[data-sveltekit-hydrate="45h"]').parentNode,
                version: "1672682689612"
            });
        </script></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Contrary to vanilla Svelte that would generate something like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="/dist/app/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

That could be served through Webview like:

```js
function getWebviewContent(webview, context) {
    return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <meta
                http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
                content="${[
          "default-src 'none'",
          `img-src ${webview.cspSource} https:`,
          `script-src ${webview.cspSource}`,
          `style-src ${webview.cspSource}`,
        ].join(';')};"
            />
      <title>My Extension</title>
            <script type="module" crossorigin src="${webview.asWebviewUri(
        vscode.Uri.joinPath(context.extensionUri, 'dist/app/main.js')
      )}"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="${webview.asWebviewUri(
        vscode.Uri.joinPath(context.extensionUri, 'dist/app/style.css')
      )}">
        </head>
        <body><div id="app"></div></body>
    </html>
  `;
}
```

The file is bit more complex now, so I can't (and shouldn't) try to rewrite it in this function.

The following are the conditions:

1. VSCode needs absolute paths since it has different environments and protocols. Keep in mind that an extension is served locally to every user. (`context.extensionUri` is IMPORTANT)
2. SvelteKit has its set of configurations (different from Vite) that may pose to be restrictive specially with SPA mode.
3. [Content Security Policy for Webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#content-security-policy) is also restrictive to what and what can't be used.
4. Probably due to Vite, the file names have hashes, so it's not consistent - but I'm preferring to keep that.
5. The script block in the HTML (may also need a `nonce`) is importing the `start` function relatively as a module.
6. Instead of writing another template as a string for VSCode that would need to be maintained, it would be ideal to have the generated HTML read into VSCode and served. Using [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) seems good (hence you see `{{cspSource}}` in the HTML above).

How would one suggest to architecture and integrate this?

Comment: I don't see any gain to switch to Sveltekit for your use case. Sveltekit is meant for building website. But you're building vscode extension here. I suggest just stick to svelte only, don't use Sveltekit. It's wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm building a SPA that SvelteKit also aims to deliver - it's (generally) the recommended way to make Svelte *apps* - and the webview would "embed" the built SPA. There's also a similar scenario where developers are now building Chrome Extensions in SvelteKit. In addition, Svelte 4 has been planned, so there's hesitation to either build on Svelte 3 or the recommended SvelteKit. From my research over this issue and discussions with the community, I'm trying to write an adapter for this case, but meanwhile the post is open if someone has another answer to this post.

Comment: Honest question: I’m curious what are the pros that you see worth the trouble? I get the FOMO on latest tech, but that’s sensational and I don’t see as good argument. Since you mentioned your research and discussion w/ community, I guess I’m missing sth. Would you like to share the specific pros that you found?

Comment: If you are able to get it working with Svelte + Vite you're going to get a lot of the benefits of Kit minus the routing, which you might not need? Kit is the preferred default option as you said, but you're also building for a unique environment so using plain Svelte seems just fine. Is there any specific Kit features you feel you need in your extension?

Comment: I found Static Site Generation (SSG), for example, in Kit quite useful! This reduces initial load of the extension and provides the generated template already.